# How to add functionality to search bar in Bootstrap 4 Dashboard Template

Tags: html, css, forms, bootstrap-4

Just downloaded the Bootstrap 4 Dashboard template and are trying to add a form to the top search bar. When I do this the search bar shrinks and loses it's design.

[Bootstrap 4 Dashboard template](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/dashboard/)

It's probably down to html/CSS by I can't figure out how to accomplish this without breaking up the design, not that familiar with the new and added CSS in Bootstrap 4.

Tried this, but like I said, the form shrinks to the center:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark sticky-top bg-dark flex-md-nowrap p-0">
  <a class="navbar-brand col-sm-4 col-md-2 mr-0" href="#">My Site</a>
    <form action="search.php" method="POST">
      <input class="form-control form-control-dark w-100" type="text" placeholder="Search">
    </form>
  <ul class="navbar-nav px-3">
    <li class="nav-item text-nowrap">
      <a class="nav-link" href="logout.php">Log out</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input tag has width:100% which is a relative value. Now that you have added form tag as the parent of the input, it must have a width of 100% too.

Try replacing the code with this for testing (given inline css for now):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark sticky-top bg-dark flex-md-nowrap p-0">
  <a class="navbar-brand col-sm-4 col-md-2 mr-0" href="#">My Site</a>
    <form action="search.php" method="POST" style="width: 100%">
      <input class="form-control form-control-dark w-100" type="text" placeholder="Search">
    </form>
  <ul class="navbar-nav px-3">
    <li class="nav-item text-nowrap">
      <a class="nav-link" href="logout.php">Log out</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just move the `w-100` from the input to the form.

```
<form action="search.php" method="POST" class="w-100">
      <input class="form-control form-control-dark" type="text" placeholder="Search">
</form>
```

[Demo](https://www.codeply.com/go/JqCTXdjHcC/dashboard-demo)

This will make the form `width:100%`.